# Parênteses em um ponteiro para ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou estudando uma estrutura de árvore binária e fiquei em dúvida em uma parte do código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree
{
  int num;
  struct tree* sad;
  struct tree* sae;
} Tree;

void insertTree(Tree** t, int num)
{

  if(*t == NULL)
  {
    *t = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree)); 
    (*t)->sae = NULL; 
    (*t)->sad = NULL;
    (*t)->num = num;
  }
}
// Código continua, porém não achei necessário colocá-lo 

int main()
{
  Tree* t = NULL;

  insertTree(&t, 12);
}
```

Minha dúvida é justamente quando se tem este parênteses no ponteiro `(*t)->sae = NULL;`

O que ele quer dizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma [tabela de precedência de operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), como você conhece na matemática (multiplicação e divisão acontece antes de adição e subtração). No caso um código de uma linguagem tem diversos operadores.

[image: tabela de precedência de operadores em C]

Como é possível ver na tabela os parênteses tem precedência máxima então tudo o que estiver dentro dele será feito antes.

```
(1 + 2) * 4
```

dá 12, é diferente de

```
1 + 2 * 4
```

que dá 9 porque na verdade é isto que ocorre implicitamente:

```
1 + (2 * 4)
```

O ponteiro tem uma precedência um pouco menor. Mas o ponteiro de um membro tem a precedência máxima, então se você tiver um ponteiro normal e de um membro o do membro será resolvido antes. A não ser que tenha parênteses forçando nova precedência. Assim

```
*t->num
```

pega o valor de `t` e tenta então pegar o objeto referenciado por `num` (`->`). Depois o que ele achar tentará derreferenciar com o `*`. Isso dará erro, não faz sentido.

O que está fazendo no seu código é derreferenciar `t` com `*` em primeiro lugar e o resultado disso é que deve pegar o objeto referenciado por `num` (`->`). Então você tem que garantir que o ponteiro (`*`) seja executado antes do ponteiro para membro (`->`).

```
(*t) -> num
```

O padrão sem nada seria o mesmo que escrever assim:

```
*(t->num)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/PrecedenceDereference.c).

Não é o que deseja.

O `(*t) -> num` está guardando algo no membro `num`, que é o desejado.

O `*(t->num)` está guardando algo no local que `t->num` indicar, que não é o que deseja.